# Angular ng-show / hide animations

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, ng-animate

I have been following the slideUp guide here: http://ng.malsup.com/#!/css-animations-for-ng-hide_ng-show

Apart from i want the opposite effect. Instead of sliding up/hiding on click, i want the content to slide down/appear on click. So, the content is hidden on load. I have created a plunker here, but doesnt seem to work: http://plnkr.co/edit/12wPKGqn4g3Fctm7NKnA

HTML:

```
<ul>
      <li ng-repeat-start="item in data">
        <p>Name: {{item.name}} <span ng-click="example1=!example1">+</span></p>
      </li>
      <li ng-repeat-end class="cssSlideUp"  ng-hide="example1">
        DOB: {{item.dob}}
        Gender: {{item.gender}}
      </li>
    </ul>
```

CSS:

```
.ng-hide-add, .ng-hide-remove {
    /* ensure visibility during the transition */
    display: block !important; /* yes, important */
}

.cssSlideUp {
    transition: .3s linear all;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.cssSlideUp.ng-hide {
    height:0;
}
```

It doesnt feel like ng-animate is being successfully added as a dependency.

---

---

UPDATE:

Updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Vwuin1KLrNUDSkfv7cBy?p=preview

Comment: Your plunker is not working because the html is not loaded, put the script before the closing body tag or run it on document loaded

Comment: @AntonioSmoljan - thanks, see updated plunker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see that demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/N6fPYgipvML2rzmEt4So?p=preview

it looks like you need to change a bit structure of your DOM

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in data">
    <p>Name: {{item.name}} <span ng-click="example1=!example1">+</span></p>

  <p  class="cssSlideUp"  ng-hide="example1">
    DOB: {{item.dob}}
    Gender: {{item.gender}}
    </p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks for the above. I think my UL structure is ok with ng-repeat-start and end.. See my updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Vwuin1KLrNUDSkfv7cBy?p=preview

Comment: The issue i am facing is that i want DOB and gender to be hidden on load.. The shown/slide down on click of  +

Comment: in that case please change ng-hide to ng-show like here http://plnkr.co/edit/atkNSTHndsw5oAv1Pc3I?p=preview

Comment: that link goes to an empty plunker

Comment: @OamPsy please try refresh it looks like plnkr is a bit overloaded today